# Progressbar and server considerations to download

Tags: ios, swift, download, progress-bar

I am implementing a progressbar and it works correctly (showing the progress of the bar and the percentage.) with the following PDF file:

```
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/KMS-Cryptographic-Details.pdf
```

But if I put my files from my server (http / https), the file does download but the progressbar does not work and in the percentage I get negative numbers. There is some consideration to keep in mind on my server (my files have permission chmod 644 and directory 755 and in my app `NSAppTransportSecurity = NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`)

Why do you work in one file and not in others?

**UPDATE:** works perfectly also with dropbox and amazon files but not with those of my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, for example, if they have a WORDPRESS installation on your server that may be causing conflict.

If the file comes from a download link type `http://myserver.com/download.php?file=s1`, be sure to add the size in the PHP file so that it can be calculated how long it will take to download the toolbar. progress `header (" Content-Length: ".filesize ($ path_to_file));`